# Add Subview to a zero size UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

Here is my problem, I add a subview to my container view while `container view`'s size is (0,0), I want my `subview` has fixed margin length is 4(top,right,left,bottom) in my `container view`. Can I achieve this goal without custom my `layOutSubviews` method.
My code is like is

```
- initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        mySubview = [[UIView alloc] init];
        //how to code here????
        [myContainerView addSubview:mySubview];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6, you should be able to do this with constraints, but prior to iOS 6, I do not recommend adding subviews prior to having a non-zero frame, or if you do, I recommend using `layoutSubviews` to fix it. It's just not possible to have a 4-point margin inside of a zero-sized box, so it's never going to autosize correctly using springs and struts.

Answer (score 0):

```
- initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        mySubview = [[UIView alloc] init];
        mySubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [myContainerView addSubview:mySubview];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: you should use `-[UIView initWithFrame:]`, not `-init`.

Answer (score 0):

What Rob Napier said... Your own `-layoutSubviews` will be simple:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [ super layoutSubviews ] ;

    CGRect insetBounds = CGRectInset( self.bounds, 4.0f, 4.0f ) ;
    self.<<the inset subview>>.frame = insetBounds ;
}
```